# xcode cannot see my class

Tags: xcode

I have a class in Classes folder of my project (a .h file and a .m file).

When I try to import it like so

```
#import <myClass.h>
```

I get an error saying "no such file or directory".

It is definitely there. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
#import "myClass.h"
```

<> are used for system libraries and "" for local and system libraries.

System libraries are the ones in directories given by the -I and -F or -framework flags on the command line of the compiler

The rules here are the same for C's #include [GNU compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC4) (with the addition for frameworks)

Comment: Thankyou!
That was driving me mad. Don't know how I didnt spot it